# What's proper way to split long video files into about equal sized parts?

Tags: command-line, video

Let's say `foo.mp4` is 3h49m06s long twitch stream recording and I want to split it into 8 sections, of about 28m40s each, to upload it into sensible parts to youtube.

I know I could divide that time by 8, then run `mencoder` or `ffmpeg` 8 times with specified start and endpos, but that still leaves issues like keyframes, not reencoding, and leaving small overlap between videos unaddressed.

So what's the "proper" way to do so?

Comment: Do it manually. Find a good time to cut it, so that viewers don't get confused why your video stops in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Even if I manually choose cuts (and that's probably too much hassle, short overlap between parts is usually good enough), that still leaves the question of the method of splitting.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find is:

`ffmpeg -i stream.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time $[60*28] -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment "stream_part_%02d.mp4"`

This splits on keyframes into about equally long segments without reencoding.

Primary downside is that you need to calculate segment size manually (if you split 3h1m video into 30m segments you'll have awkward 7th 1m segment). In this example i used 28m segments as that was closest to even.

Minor downside is that it number generated files from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully use a third-party video conversion tool called [Pavtube Video Converter Ultimate](http://www.pavtube.com/video_converter/) to split my 2 hours movie into 5 parts with equal length.

Comment: I find it funny that both the person that wrote this response and the person that edited it failed to even read the question prompt. It clearly states equal size parts not equal length.